# Discord Py Tempban

Tags: discord.py

```
@loop(seconds=10)
async def tempun(client):
    db_name = "database/tempban.db"
    db = await aiosqlite.connect(db_name)
    try:
        cur = await db.execute("SELECT * FROM tempban")
        fetch = await cur.fetchall()
        cur_time = datetime.utcnow()
        for row in fetch:
            ban_time = parser.parse(row[2])
            print(ban_time)
            if cur_time >= ban_time:
                unbanuser = int(row[1])
                guilduser = int(row[0])
                try:
                    member = discord.Object(id=unbanuser)
                    guild = await client.fetch_guild(guilduser)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                try:
                    await guild.unban(member, reason="Tempban expired")
                    deletetime = await cur.execute("delete from tempban where guild_id = ? AND user_id = ? returning *", (guilduser, unbanuser,))
                    await db.commit()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The Code won´t Give any Errors it does nothing it prints the datetime from a user of my database all database values are there.

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to use the `asyncio` library.

```
import asyncio

async def tempun(client):
   # get data from the database
   await asyncio.sleep(seconds_to_sleep)
   await guild.unban(user, reason)
   # delete from database
```

The tempun function can be called in the ban command or wherever it needs to be triggered